wireguard routing. vps1 -> wireguard -> vps2 -> internet. Error curl: Could not resolve host

I have vps1 with ip, for ex. 100.100.100.100, with wgp2.conf:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = vps1.priv
Address = 20.0.20.1/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = vps2.pub
AllowedIPs = 20.0.20.3/32
Endpoint = 200.200.200.200:51821
PersistentKeepalive = 20


I also have vps2 with ip, for ex. 200.200.200.200, with wgp1.conf:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = vps2.priv
Address = 20.0.20.3/24  
ListenPort = 51821
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = vps1.pub
AllowedIPs = 20.0.20.1/32


IP RULES


on vps1 ip forwarding is enabled.
on vps2 ip forwarding is enabled.
on vps2 iptable rules by sudo iptables -S && sudo iptables -t nat -S:

-P FORWARD ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i wgp1 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -o wgp1 -j ACCEPT 
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT 
-P INPUT ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT 
-A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE

HOW IT REAL WORKING:

when on vps1 wg-quick down wgp2: the command curl --interface ens3 ifconfig.me returns vps1's ip 100.100.100.100
BUT:

when on vps1 wg-quick up wgp2: the command curl --interface ens3 ifconfig.me returns error curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.me
when on vps1 wg-quick up wgp2: the command curl --interface wgp2 ifconfig.me returns error curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.me



I EXPECT:

when on vps1 wg-quick up wgp2: the command curl --interface ens3 ifconfig.me returns vps1's ip 100.100.100.100
when on vps1 wg-quick up wgp2: the command curl --interface wgp2 ifconfig.me returns vps2's ip 200.200.200.200

What should i add to iptables if i want EXPECT?

One thing that jumps out immediately is that your wireguard configuration is  blocking your outbound traffic. When you run...
curl --interface wgp2 ifconfig.me

...this will attempt to contact ifconfig.me over wgp2, but your wireguard configuration has AllowedIPs = 20.0.20.3/32. Since the address of ifconfig.me is not 20.0.20.3, this traffic will be dropped.
You need to update your wireguard configuration to allow any ip address over the link. On vps1:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = vps1.priv
Address = 20.0.20.1/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = vps2.pub
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 200.200.200.200:51821
PersistentKeepalive = 20

And on vps2:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = vps2.priv
Address = 20.0.20.3/24  
ListenPort = 51821
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = vps1.pub
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

With this configuration in place, your test using curl --interface wgp2 ... should work.
You can find the containerized setup I used to test this out here.
